# Adding Condition to a Button (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I want to add a condition to a button.

So if the condition is true another view will be opened through a segue!

Otherwise, nothing happens and an alert will appear to the user.

The two views are linked by a navigational controller.

```
 @IBAction func AddButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AddDevice", sender: nil)

    }
    else {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message:"You have to Register First", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { _ in })
        self.present(alert, animated: true){}
    }

}
```

Here's what I have tried! But it did not give the result I want.

Comment: What's wrong with the code? I think it will work well.

Comment: It seems that I was using  `self.shouldPerformSegue` instaid of  `self.performSegue`

Comment: So that's why it did not work! I was doing it in haste, I have not noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```
 @IBAction func AddButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
    if let user = user {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AddDevice", sender: nil)
     } 
    else {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message:"You have to Register First", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { _ in })
    self.present(alert, animated: true){}
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: The other view has opened! Even if the condition is not true!

Comment: Try and connect the segue from one view controller to the other, instead of from button to view controller. In my end i works fine, i have replaced your FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil with a test string and i check if its not empty perform the segue otherwise don't.

Comment: I have updated my answer, if you check Firebase documentation: "currentUser might also be nil because the auth object has not finished initializing. If you use a listener to keep track of the user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case."

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123744/discussion-between-do2-and-mariah).

Comment: I'm getting error (crash if the user not logged in!)

Comment: I have replied to you in chat to avoid lengthy comments